# Where do uncaught exceptions go with asynchronous I/O

Tags: c#, exception

I am developing a console-based .NET application (using mono). I'm using asynchronous I/O (Begin/EndReceive).

I'm in the middle of a callback chain several layers deep, and if an exception is thrown, it is not being trapped anywhere (having it bubble out to the console is what I would expect, as there is currently no exception handling).

However, looking at the stack trace when I log it at the point where it occurs, the stack doesn't show it reaching back to the initial point-of-execution.

I've tried the AppDomain.UnhandledException trick, but that doesn't work in this situation.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
Parameter name: size
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive (System.Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socket_flags, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00000] 
  at MyClass+State.BeginReceive () [0x00000]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe any error generated during an asynchronous call should be thrown upon calling the *EndAction* method (*EndReceive* in your case). At least, this is what I've experienced using the CLR (MSFT) implementation, and Mono should be doing the same thing, although it *may* perhaps be slightly buggy here (consider this as unlikely however). If you were in Visual Studio, I would recommend you turn on the option for catching all exceptions (i)n the Debug > Exceptions menu) - perhaps there is a similar option in whatever IDE you are using?

Comment: During the asynchronous call, yes. You can use Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult, SocketError) to retrieve a SocketError that occurred. But in this case, BeginReceive never starts, as my 'size' argument is out-of-range.

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't notice that. In this case, have you tried running the code on Windows under the CLR? That would help narrow down whether it's a Mono issue at least.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of the stack, the exception is being thrown in the BeginReceive, so that particular I/O operation is not being initiated at all.

The default behaviour (since CLR2.0) of an unhandled exception on a thread-pool thread is to terminate the process, so if you are not seeing this, then something is catching the exception.

Comment: How do I determine what may be catching it?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the bit about it being Mono, and I don't know if this affects things as I have no experience of this platform. I would break at the point the exception is thrown then single-step to where it is caught. It maybe that your version of Mono silently swallows thread-pool exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft's .NET usually most exceptions thrown during async calls are raised within the async callback method, except few cases. To handle the rest I usually set a timeout callback method.